# Relation between same users table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, roles

I've got 3 different roles (`Admin`, `Coach` and `Runner`). A user has only one role.

The issue is when I try to relate a user with role Coach and user with role Runner. Logic app is this one; I can create runners and coaches but each runner belongs only to one coach and one coach has many runners.

How can I handle this on same Users table and then on User model and their relations.

Comment: If you were to split 'users' table into 3 tables: admin, coach, runner - would they be identical?

Comment: Mmm, at the beginning I've model for separate Coach and Runner tables but I wanted a kind of simplification. I'm thinking on revert this idea and get back coaches and runners table asociated with a user id.

Comment: What if you create the column `coach_id` in `users` table? It will be nullable and only required for runners to be specified.

Comment: @Makros what I'm trying to imply is - if your admins, coaches and runners tables had identical columns - then sure, you should use just one table - but then maybe have a column that's an enum or a bitflag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need your foreign key to be `nullable`, you can specify this in your user's [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#migration-structure) file:

**your_migration_file.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        // your columns
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('coach_id')->nullable();  // <-----
    }); //                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

> Notice that doing this you won't be able to add database constrains, but this isn't necessary anyways. Also, you might need to [refresh your migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#rolling-back-migrations).

Then in your `User` model you need to define your relationships:

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model {

    /** a Runner has a Coach. */
    public function coach()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'coach_id');
    }

    /** a Coach teaches many Runners */
    public function runners()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'coach_id');
    }
```

Then you could make your queries to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and constraint the results:

**YourController.php**

```
public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $runners = User::with('coach')->whereNotNull('coach_id')->get();
    $coaches = User::with('runners')->whereNull('coach_id')->get();
}
```

Of course this queries look ugly so you could define [local query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) in your `User` model aswell:

```
class User extends Model {

    // some code..

    public function scopeCoaches($query)
    {
        return $query->hasRole('coach'); // maybe you use a role package?            
     // return $query->whereNull('coach_id'); // or my basic approach used before
    }

    public function scopeRunners($query)
    {
        return $query->hasRole('srunner'); // maybe you use a role package?            
     // return $query->whereNotNull('coach_id'); // or my basic approach used before
    }
}
```

Then just use your scopes:

```
public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $runners = User::with('coach')->coaches()->get();
    $coaches = User::with('runners')->runners()->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @HCK. Just the one I need.